Rows have a data type and a Y/N field - How to summarize how many Yes / No there are per data type?
I have a table that I want to analyze by data type, which is a field in my row entries. Each row also has one (actually multiple) boolean fields - I would now like to summarize, for each category, how many entries in that category are "Yes" and how many are "No".
What would be the easiest way of doing so? A classic pivot table just counts the number of entries per data type in general, unless I can configure it better?
Thank you!

Can you share a data sample using Markdown Table generator? There's probably a fairly easy formula, but without any data it's hard to generate one. Also, have you tried anything else? Does it have to be a pivot-table?

Doesn't have to be a pivot table. For data, just imagine the rows having columns "Type", "Condition", with type being any kind of text and Condition being Yes / No. I want to now group by "Type", and count how many Yes's and how many No's each type has.

I still recommend you [edit] in a data sample, it will get more people to help you, because they can instantly see what you want from just the question body. Some people don't like reading the comments/comments might be deleted over time.

Two ways of doing this, from what I understand of your question and comment.


Pivot table:



Use TYPE as rows, Condition as both values and filters, select either type in the filter to give the right amount.

Formula:
=COUNTIFS(B2:B25,"Y",A2:A25,D2#)
Change "Y" into "N" for the second column.
With A2:A25 being your 'type' range, and B2:B25 your 'condition' range.


